# Where to see the reason for deleted answer?

Tags: support, answers

I've asked a question and I've received an answer, but then the author deleted the answer. Can I see the reason for deletion?

Comment: Looking at the answer in question, I think it's because the answerer didn't notice that you wanted to rotate the plane in the BGE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing an answer is up to the author for whatever reason they choose, no notification or message is shown and you cannot see deleted posts unless you have the [privilege](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (unlocked at 2000+ reputation).